# how do you estimate the parameters of a system~(alpha,beta) in R?

Tags: r, estimation, weibull-distribution

Given a system made up of **n** different components who follow a Weibull distribution. we can easily estimate both the shape and scale parameters for each component. if the components forms a parralel system, how do you estimate the parameters of the whole system?